# How to use password_verify function in PHP

Tags: php, security, passwords

I am writing a basic website login script in PHP (login_config.php).

My question is: Am I implementing the password_verify() function properly in regards to user security/protection?

-Note: Post data is being sent from login.php

CODE (LOGIN_CONFIG.PHP):

```
        <?php                       //POST VARIABLES
    $submit = $_POST['login_submit'];
    $username = $_POST['login_username'];
    $password = $_POST['login_password'];
    $email = $_POST['login_email'];

    require 'password_config.php';
    if(isset($submit)){
    require 'db/connect.php';
    //PASSWORD VERIFYING
    $pass_query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $queried = mysql_query($pass_query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queried)){
    $user_pass = $row['password'];
    $veri_password = password_verify($password, $user_pass);
    }
    if(!$veri_password === true){$errors[] = '-Account does not exist ';}
```

EDIT: I am aware of other flaws, please regard to the initial question.

Comment: You can simplify `if(!$veri_password === true){` to `if(!$veri_password) {`... but switch to a db interface that supports prepared statements/bind vars

Comment: I would worry more about that huge sql injection hole instead...

Comment: .. and the use of deprecated mysql_ calls...

Comment: Ahaha yes, that is the next thing to do.

Comment: -Also I cannot use mysqli_* due to web hosting.

Comment: You can use for db PDO.

Comment: I know you say don't worry about the security issues, but you better fix them or you will get owned day 1. Just sayin

Comment: If your host doesn't let you use mysqli_* or PDO, they are depriving you of the ability to use prepared statements, which are [the *only* proven solution to SQL injection](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correctly using the [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function **as long as** `$row['password']` is returning the *correspondent password hash*  created by [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) of the plain password, and not the plain password itself or any other value than that.

> Note that no further security concerns are included in this answer.

Comment: - The above code structure does indeed match my code, thank you for answering my question.